# How can I stop a github project page (or other subpage) from showing custom domain name?

Tags: dns, github, cname

I'm using GitHub pages to host my blog. I've set up a CNAME record in the repository and added an A record and CNAME record to my domain registrar (123-reg). This is working fine so now my personal page [donskifarrell.github.com](http://donskifarrell.github.com) -> [donalfarrell.com](http://www.donalfarrell.com).

This also makes all my project pages map to the same new domain, eg. [donskifarrell.github.com/calex](http://donskifarrell.github.com/calex) -> [donalfarrell.com/calex](http://www.donalfarrell.com/calex).

While this is quite nice to have, it is proving to be troublesome for one of my projects.

Is there any way to modify my setup so that certain project pages do not use my own custom domain and instead retain the github url?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really a way to prevent the redirect from happening.

However, if it will help to have that project at a different domain or a subdomain, you can use a `CNAME` file in the **project**'s `gh-pages` branch to override your user redirect with a project-specific one.

See more info at the bottom of: https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages